# stop sound of video within div styled with display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a video within videoDiv. videoDiv that is styled to display:none. However, the audio of the video does start playing. How can I make it so not have the sound play also when the videoDiv is set to display: none?

```css
#videoDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: relative;
}
#videoBlock,
#videoMessage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.videoClick {
  text-align: center
}
.videoClick a {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.25);
  font-size: 1.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand
}
```

```html
<div id="videoDiv" style="display:none">
  <div id="videoBlock">
    <video preload="preload" id="video" loop="loop">
      <source src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/093143183/fotel-photography-course-tour-workshop-video-4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want  to play in the background a video that users will not be able to see but also not be able to listen?

Comment: What I actually want is for the video to start playing when It is made visible.

Comment: Then that should be the question, not how to mute a video

Comment: The videoDiv should not be visible when the video is not displaying.

Comment: Start by removing the `autoplay` attribute

Comment: I thought display:none would not have the video playing in the background.

Comment: autoplay attribute is removed

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/1b0Lbdnh/

Comment: Thank you very much , Adeneo! When I toggle the sounds starts, but the video does not. Need to toggle it again twice to also see the video. PLUS: is it also possible that the video (with its sound) starts at the beginning each time its toggled?

Comment: @Eddy check my updated answer. It starts and stop the video(of course and sound).

Comment: @Adeneo and Vassilis Pits, please check my posted answer" This works. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do it is this:

```js
$( "#videoDiv" ).click(function() {
  
  $("#video").css('display', 'block');
  
  var video = $("#video").get(0);

    if ( video.paused ) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
    }

  
});
```

```css
#videoDiv {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 360px;
  position: relative; 
  cursor: pointer;
  background: gray;
}
#videoDiv video {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="videoDiv">

    <video preload="preload" id="video"loop="loop">
      <source src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/093143183/fotel-photography-course-tour-workshop-video-4.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works: [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/1b0Lbdnh/4/)

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
var videoDiv = $('#videoDiv').toggle();

if ( videoDiv.is(':visible') ) {
    $('#video').get(0).load();
    $('#video').get(0).play();
} else {
$('#video').get(0).pause();
$('#video').get(0).unload();

}
```

});